# Trying to make a line caster in python

Tags: python, numpy, math

Hello I am trying to make a line caster for those who don't know what that is it is a thing that gives you all the point in between 2 points and in this case I am writing this data to an image but for some reason when I run it it will only go up to the right (you will see what I mean if you run the code) does anyone know why this is
here is my code and I am more than aware it is messy and not very efficient so suggestions to make it more efficient and or less messy are welcome

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
dim_x = 50
dim_y = 50
x1 = 8
x2 = 40
y1 = 8
y2 = 30
count = 0
def calc(cord, target):
    x = abs(cord[0] - target[0])
    y = abs(cord[1] - target[1])
    return(abs(x+y))

def starter(x1,x2,y1,y2):
    x = abs(x1-x2)
    y = abs(y1-y2)
    z = x1-x2
    if z == abs(z):
        right = 1
    else:
        right = 0
    return(x+y, right)
distance,direction = starter(x1,x2,y1,y2)
# for direction 1 = left and 0 = right
print(distance,direction)
pic = np.zeros((dim_y,dim_x))
pic[x1,y1] = 255
pic[x2,y2] = 255
while True:
   
    top_r = (x1+1,y1+1)
    mid_r = (x1+1,y1)
    but_r = (x1+1,y1-1)
    top = (x1,y1+1)
    mid = (x1,y1)
    but= (x1,y1-1)
    top_l = (x1-1, y1+1)
    mid_l = (x1-1, y1)
    but_l = (x1-1,y1-1)
    top_r2 = calc(top_r,np.array((x2,y2)))
    mid_r2 = calc(mid_r,np.array((x2,y2)))
    but_r2 = calc(but_r,np.array((x2,y2)))
    top2 = calc(top,np.array((x2,y2)))
    mid2 = calc(mid,np.array((x2,y2)))
    but2 = calc(but,np.array((x2,y2)))
    top_l2 = calc(top_l,np.array((x2,y2)))
    mid_l2 = calc(mid_l,np.array((x2,y2)))
    but_l2 = calc(but_l,np.array((x2,y2)))
    if top_r2 < mid_r2 and top_r2 < but_r2 and top_r2 < top2 and  top_r2 < mid2 and top_r2 < but2 and top_r2 < top_l2  and top_r2 < mid_l2 and top_r2 < but_l2:
        print("top")
        pic[top_r] = 255
        x1 = top_r[0]
        y1 = top_r[1]
        
    elif mid_r2 < mid_r2 and mid_r2 < but_r2 and mid_r2 < top2 and mid_r2 < top_r2 and mid_r2 < but2 and mid_r2 < top_l2  and mid_r2 < mid_l2 and mid_r2 < but_l2:
        print("mid")
        pic[mid_r] = 255
        x1 = mid_r[0]
        y1 = mid_r[1]
    elif but_r2 < mid_r2 and mid_r2 < top_r2 and mid_r2 < top2 and mid_r2 < mid2 and mid_r2 < but2 and  mid_r2 < top_l2  and mid_r2 < mid_l2 and mid_r2 < but_l2:
        print("but")
        pic[but_r] = 255
        x1 = but_r[0]
        y1 = but_r[1]
    elif top2 < mid_r2 and top2 < but_r2 and top2 < top_r2 and top2 < mid2 and top2 < but2 and top2 < top_l2 and top2 < mid_l2 and top2 < but_l2:
        print("top2")
        pic[top] = 255
        x1 = top[0]
        y1 = top[1]
    elif mid2 < mid_r2 and mid2 < but_r2 and mid2 < top2 and mid2 < mid_r2 and mid2 < but2 and mid2 < top_l2  and mid2 < mid_l2 and mid2 < but_l2:
        print("mid2")
        pic[mid] = 255
        x1 = mid[0]
        y1 = mid[1]
        break
    elif but2 < mid_r2 and but2 <  top_r2 and but2 <  top2 and but2 <  mid2 and but2 <  but_r2 and but2 <  top_l2  and but2 <  mid_l2 and but2 <  but_l2:
        print("but2")
        pic[but] = 255
        x1 = but[0]
        y1 = but[1]
    elif top_l2 < mid_r2 and top_l2 < but_r2 and top_l2 < top2 and top_l2 < mid2 and top_l2 < but2 and top_l2 < top_r2  and top_l2 < mid_l2 and top_l2 < but_l2:
        print("top3")
        pic[top_l] = 255
        x1 = top_l[0]
        y1 = top_l[1]
    elif mid_l2 < mid_r2 and mid_l2 < but_r2 and mid_l2 < top2 and mid_l2 < top_r2 and mid_l2 < but2 and mid_l2 < top_l2  and mid_l2 < mid_r2 and mid_l2 < but_l2:
        print("mid4")
        pic[mid_l] = 255
        x1 = mid_l[0]
        y1 = mid_l[1]
    elif  but_l2 < mid_r2 and but_l2 < top_r2 and but_l2 < top2 and but_l2 < mid2 and but_l2 < but2 and but_l2 < top_l2  and but_l2 < mid_l2 and but_l2 < but_r2:
        print("but5")
        pic[but_l] = 255
        x1 = but_l[0]
        y1 = but_l[1]
    print(x1,y1)
    if count == 0:
        break
    count +=1
cv.imwrite("frame.png", pic)
```

Comment: Are you just trying to draw a line from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)?

Comment: If you are looking to draw a line from one point to another try searching google for "bresenham's line algorithm"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question seems to *"Need more focus"*, please consider the guidelines [*"Why are some questions closed??"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way you draw a line between two points.  This is based on Bresenham's algorithm.  You figure out which direction has the largest change, and that is your "major" direction.  Then, at every step, you move one in the major direction.  You keep an "error term", which tracks how far along you need to move in the "minor" direction, and when that crosses a whole unit, you move in the minor direction as well.  Also note that, in numpy terms, the Y coordinate (rows) should always be first.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
dim_x = 50
dim_y = 50

x1,y1 = (8,8)
y2,y2 = (40,30)

# Are we increasing in X?

deltax = x2 - x1
deltay = y2 - y1

dirx = 1 if deltax > 0 else -1
diry = 1 if deltay > 0 else -1

# Which direction is major?

if deltax > deltay:
    steps = deltax
    xmajor = 1
else:
    steps = deltay
    xmajor = 0

error = 0

pic = np.zeros((dim_y,dim_x))
pic[y1,x1] = 255
pic[y2,x2] = 255
for count in range(steps):
    if xmajor:
        x1 += dirx
        error += deltay
        if error >= deltax:
            y1 += diry
            error -= deltax
    else:
        y1 += diry
        error += deltax
        if error >= deltay:
            x1 += dirx
            error -= deltay
    pic[y1,x1] = 255
    print(x1,y1)
cv.imwrite("frame.png", pic)
```